# Is Quarkus dev mode / live coding not working with JPMS/Java Modules?

Tags: java, quarkus, java-platform-module-system

I recently played around with Quarkus and wanted to try out using JPMS modules alongside with it.

So I went to code.quarkus.io and generated a basic application with just the RESTEasy JAX-RS extension enabled.
After unpacking, all I did was include a `module-info.java` in `src/main/java` and add the `requires java.ws.rs;` line.

Now, building the Jar with Maven works fine. Starting the live coding with the `quarkus:dev` mode works fine too. But when I change some of my code and try another request, I get an error page stating `java.lang.RuntimeException: Compilation failed[error: module not found: java.ws.rs]`.

To me, it looks like the dev mode of Quarkus does not set the module path correctly. I already did a fair bit of searching for a solution but came up short. Am I missing a configuration or is this a bug/missing feature?

Comment: ...and are you on the latest versions of libraries used here?

Comment: I didn't change anything in the pom.xml of the generated project from code.quarkus.io. The version of Quarkus and the Quarkus Maven Plugin set is "1.13.6.Final", which seems to be the most current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit JPMS support in Quarkus